# How to create a list like this [1,1,1,1,1,2,2]?

Tags: python, list

I have looked all over and know how to make lists like this:
`[1,1,1,1,1,1]`

and like this:
`[1,2,3,4,5]`

But can't figure out how to make a list like this:
`[1,1,1,1,1,2,2]`.

I've tried this:

```
flagpriority = [[1 for i in range(len(res)-2)]]
```

and then played with putting `2,2` in there but it turns it into 2 lists or just gives me `1,1`.

Comment: It's not clear quite what your logic is there. Perhaps `[1 if x < 5 else 2 for x in range(7)]`? Or something like `[x // 5 + 1 for  x in range(7)]`?

Comment: It doesn't like <:

Comment: File "<ipython-input-20-75775f0b9547>", line 4
    flagpriority = [[1 for i < (len(res)-2) else 2 for i in range(len(res))]]
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax3

Comment: You have a `for` where there should be an `if`. Also you have a list in a list.

Comment: flagpriority = [[1 if i in range (len(res)-2) else 2 for i in range(len(res))]]

Comment: @Celeste Try this: `flagpriority = [1 if i < 5 else 2 for i in range(len(res))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
flagpriority = [1] * (len(res)-2) + [2] * 2
```